# Send WooCommerce Email on Address Save using woocommerce_email_actions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-filter

I've been struggling with this for a couple days now and have been through every post/comment/discussion/etc... I could find trying to find a working solution.

I want to send an email via a custom class that extends WC_Email whenever a woocommerce user updates their address.  I've found various resources explaining how to create custom wc emails ([skyverge was most useful](http://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/)) and I have successfully done that.  I have a plugin that adds a custom email in WP-Admin->WooCommerce->Settings->Emails.

If I use an action that is already part of the woocommerce_email_actions such as `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );` and manually change the order status in the backend everything works just fine.

Problem is I want to use `add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );` and unfortunately it never fires.

Based on some other threads I've tried adding the following to my main plugin file

```
function new_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_customer_save_address';
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'new_woocommerce_email_actions' );
```

Supposedly this should allow me to use the action in my custom class, but no luck.  I've also tried adding other actions without any success.  For instance using the filter to add woocommerce_order_status_cancelled won't fire when manually changing the order to cancelled.  I'm struggling to figure out why this isn't working and most of the the threads I've found are 2+ years old and dead, so here I am.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer in case others are trying to get this functionality working.

I found [this article from Tyche Softwares](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/create-custom-email-templates-woocommerce/) after extensive digging and was able to create [a plugin](https://github.com/jsaxestaral/wc-address-update-alert) that will send a custom WC_Email whenever a customer updates their address information.

I'm still not 100% as to why the add_filter('woocommerce_email_actions'... wasn't working, and if anyone can tell me why I'd still be interested.

This plugin works by calling a custom action defined in my extended WC_Email class via do_action whenever the existing woocommerce_customer_save_address action happens.